# Authenticating a nodejs server with Firebase 3

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

The docs seem to suggest the only way to authenticate a server with firebase 3 is to have a service account for that server, which sounds like a terrible solution security-wise - I want my private keys secure, not in my server's RAM where they are vulnerable for attack.

I already have a server authenticating my apps using a custom token which is created in a secure manner, is there any way I can use a token to authenticate my node.js server?